# Writing a P2P chat application in Python

Tags: python, twisted

Is it possible to write a peer-to-peer chat application in Python?

I am thinking of this from a hobbyist project point-of-view. Can two  machines connect to each other directly without involving a server? I have always wondered this, but never actually seen it implemented anywhere so I am thinking there must be a catch somewhere.

PS: I intend to learn Twisted, so if that is involved, it would be an added advantage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can do this pretty easily with Twisted. Just have one of the peers act like a server and the other one act like a client. In fact, the twisted tutorial will get you most of the way there.

The only problem you're likely to run into is firewalls. Most people run their home machines behind SNAT routers, which make it tougher to connect directly to them from outside. You can get around it with port forwarding though.

Comment: To deal with the problem of firewalls, you might take a look at http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodVertex

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each computer (as long as their on the same network) can establish a server instance with inbound and outbound POST/GET.

Answer (score 0):

I think i am way too late in putting my two bits here, i accidentally stumbled upon here as i was also searching on similar lines. I think you can do this fairly easily using just sockets only, however as mentioned above one of the machines would have to act like a server, to whome the other will connect.

I am not familiar with twisted, but i did achieved this using just sockets. But yes even i am curious to know how would you achieve peer2peer chat communication if there are multiple clients connected to a server. Creating a chat room kind of app is easy but i am having hard time in thinking how to handle peer to peer connections.

Comment: Can you explain how you deal with users in different networks? using TCP in a local networks works well but if the end points are behind routers there is an issue finding the correct ports. As described above portforwarding solve the problem, but that force users to manually temper with the router configuration. Although this can be done automatically, I have not been able to do so using python.